# Javascript do while bucle

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a sript that generates a random number, then the script anwsers a number, and it tells if the number is higher or lower.

The problem comes when the number is correct, here is the code:

```
const rl = require('readline-sync');
let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
let b=0;
let n = 0;
console.log(a)


do {

    let b = rl.questionFloat("Dime un numero ");
    n++;
    if (a < b) {
        console.log("El número es menor");
    } else if (a > b) {
        console.log("El numero es mayor");

    }} while (a !== b);

  
    console.log("has usado " + n);
```

The output is:

```
74
Dime un numero 75
El número es menor
Dime un numero 76 
El número es menor
Dime un numero 73 
El numero es mayor
Dime un numero 74 
Dime un numero
```

I would aprecitate very much your help, as I'm starting learning this.

Cheers

Comment: I forgot say that I would like that when the number is correct the sript shows : "has usado " +n

Comment: Where is the code run? On a browser, or on a Node server?

Comment: In VS code it's node js :/

Comment: It may be worth reading a bit more about let and scope see e.g. [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#:~:text=Variables%20declared%20by%20let%20have%20their%20scope%20in,a%20var%20variable%20is%20the%20entire%20enclosing%20function%3A

Comment: Welcome!
A scope problem:
Your `b` in `while` is not the global `b`.
Remove the `let` inside `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `b` twice. Once outside the loop in the outer scope and once inside the loop in the inner scope. The `b` variable in the outer scope is the one being checked in the condition `while (a !== b)` and is always `0`.